# How does pnpm-lock.yaml work in mono repo

Tags: npm, package, bazel, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I am at present working on npm to pnpm migration. I have couple of doubts.

The project structure goes like this:

**Before:**

- Root

  - projectAUsingGo
  - projectAUsingPython
  - UI

    - web (main project)

      - package.json
    - shared-ui(workspace)

      - package.json
      - e2e(testing project)

        - package.json

Considering this structure, created `pnpm-workspace.yaml` in the `Root` folder and also added a `package.json` in the root folder to target the mono-repos inside `ui/web` directory.

**After:**

- Root

  - projectAUsingGo
  - projectAUsingPython
  - package.json
  - pnpm-workspace.yaml
  - UI

    - web(main project which includes dependencies)

      - package.json
    - shared-ui(local workspace without any dependencies installation)

      - package.json
      - e2e(testing project which includes dependencies)

        - package.json

Now with the above structure, pnpm-lock.yaml i.e the replacement for package-lock.json will be located in the Root folder and that holds all the nested project dependencies as well.

I have a problem here, for some reasons npm install with legacy peer deps works and app runs successfully when migrated from node-14 to node-16.

Though with pnpm similar options didnt work, so i imported the package-lock.json and converted to pnpm-lock.yaml earlier inside ui/web. But that has to be served from root during Bazel integration.

Not sure how to manage this scenario? Any ideas / suggestions would be very helpful.

pnpm install --filter main-project e2e will refer to package.json now or it will refer to available pnpm-lock.yaml dependencies?

If the project can rely everything from lock-file within root, then problem gets solved. Looking forward to hear on this.

my **.npmrc** goes like this

```
registry=https://private-registry/
auto-install-peers=true
legacy-peer-deps=true
save-exact=true
node-linker=hoisted
link-workspace-packages=deep
```